# Renaming cross reference link in framemaker

Tags: documentation, framemaker

I have documentation for my code that I maintain in Doxygen (general description + API reference). Our documentation team working with FrameMaker so I generate an XML output for them which were imported to FrameMaker using some template file which I do not fully understand. We reached good maturity and it works well except I cannot generate internal references with a custom naming. i.e. with the XML input below :

```
<ref refid="group__ip__class_1gaad23d5c191f1ede03638140cb21ca31f" kindref="member">actions</ref>
```

I would expect that link text will be *action*, but currently, *action* just attached as a text after the link with link text taken from element referenced by ***refid***.

I have found many ways to control a text of link text [here](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/framemaker/2017/using/using-framemaker-2017/frm_single_sourcing/Manage_cross-references-.htm#XREF_WS053b9687b4c35b121b0ca95), but all of them as far as I understand working with target link text and do not provide a way for the custom text from the ref element.

I can modify my XML in way it's needed and can manipulate templates in FrameMaker (almost 0 knowledge here).
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, 
Ilya.

Comment: As far as can see the doxygen generated `<ref... </ref>` is OK, so there must be something in the processing of the xml file to framemaker that is not OK ans should be corrected. Note also that there is no `refid` element, `refid` is an attribute of the `ref` tag.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the text to "element referenced by refid". I know that XML is correct the problem is how to define it correctly within the FrameMaker, maybe I should remove the XML and Doxygen tag, my question is to FrameMaker gurus.